# Problems working with Google Calendar Api V3 and PHP

Tags: api, calendar, google-calendar-api

I'm just trying to make a little, simple application (that i already made two years ago in Objective-C with api V1) that presents a screen with time of event and description and a button : "insert event in your calendar".
Every user has, obviously, to configure the application with his google username and password.
The app simplifies some process using the first calendar available.

I had infinite problem trying to do it with javascript (this app will be made in html5), so, looking at docs, I ended up trying to make a back-end on my server in php5 (thought it could be easier...ohohoho).

So, i read docs from here : https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/
What i did :
1)
Get to the Google Developers Console.
Created  a project.

### I now have this (not real keys):

OAuth 2.0

Client ID   352xxxyy9.apps.googleusercontent.com

Email address   3527xxxy@developer.gserviceaccount.com

Service Account

Client ID   3523xxxyy419-vpfgdfg9u77s0.apps.googleusercontent.com

Email address   35ssss9-zzzzsnhavna78ea0b9gvn6a9u77s0@developer.gserviceaccount.com

Public key fingerprints  :ac15ddfxdffrtg5565fgfg545r

---

2)
I installed Google APIs Client Library for PHP (beta) in my server.

doc says:

> Using the Google APIs Client Library for PHP requires that you download the PHP source. In the future, packages will be provided. Refer to the project page for more details.

Run the following commands to download and install the source: svn blaj blah blah.

I copied the entire source in my server. Easy :)

Then..

3) You can now import the classes you will need using the following statements:

```
require_once "../src/apiClient.php";
require_once "../src/contrib/apiCalendarService.php";
```

Ok, i'll insert them in my php script !

4)" Configure your app"
You must instantiate a client to make requests to the API. All requests to the Google Calendar API require authorization.

The following code demonstrates how to configure an authorized service object using OAuth 2.0 for native applications. For more information, see Authorize Requests.

To find your project's client ID and client secret, do the following:

Go to the Google Developers Console.
Select a project.
In the sidebar on the left, select APIs & auth. In the displayed list of APIs, make sure the Google Calendar API status is set to ON.
In the sidebar on the left, select Credentials.
Find the lines labeled Client ID and Client secret. Note that there may be a client ID without a client secret, for use with Compute Engine and App Engine; in that case, create a new client ID and client secret by selecting Create New Client ID.

### Edit the src/config.php file to put in your developer API information.

```
global $apiConfig;

$apiConfig = array(
    // Site name to show in Google's OAuth authentication screen
    'site_name' => 'www.example.org',

    // OAuth2 Setting, you can get these keys in Google Developers Console
    'oauth2_client_id' => 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
    'oauth2_client_secret' => 'YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET',
    'oauth2_redirect_uri' => 'YOUR_REDIRECT_URL',

    // The developer key; you get this from Google Developers Console
    'developer_key' => 'YOUR_DEVELOPER_KEY',
    ...

    // Which Authentication, Storage and HTTP IO classes to use.
    'authClass' => 'apiOAuth2',
    ....

    // Definition of service specific values like scopes, OAuth token URLs, etc
    'services' => array(
        'calendar' => array('scope' => 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'),
    )
);
```

---

But they are DIFFERENT from the key i have, what's wrong ????

What are client secrets ? redirect_url??

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to setup a service account access as described here: 
https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/wiki/OAuth2#Service_Accounts

I had difficulties to get it work as I made many trial and errors and my cache got filled with non-working token.
If ever you find yourself not able to access the calendar even after following all the steps, try to change this line of code:

```
$client->setAssertionCredentials(new Google_AssertionCredentials(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME, array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/prediction'),$key));
```

to this:

```
$client->setAssertionCredentials(new Google_AssertionCredentials(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME, array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/prediction'),$key, 'notasecret','http://oauth.net/grant_type/jwt/1.0/bearer',false,false));
```

The last `false` tells AssertionCredential class to not use any cache. I did it once and then it worked with it set to `true` afterward.

Answer (score 0):

First go here https://console.developers.google.com/project that is where you configure your app...

Click on your project, then on the left side you will see APIs & Auth, click on Credentials. You will need to create your OAuth, and Public API Access keys.

Once you have done that you will then enter those into the appropriate client_id, secret, redirect etc.

The redirect uri is the same page your app is on, its the page the user gets sent back to after authorizing.

Comment: ok, thanks bowenac. I managed to include php client and i am now able to fetch "calendar id" from google calendar service. But my need is a bit different. The php example i tried ask me to authenticate (oauth2). My need is to have an appa (ios/android/webapp) that asks user his google calendar credentials (user/pwd) and then passes those  to my php script that enters in HIS OWN calendar the event chosen in the app.  I dont' know if i'm sufficiently clear. I read something about "offline" mode ? i'm doing mess ? :)  Thanks !

Comment: That is what I was wanting to do as well. I thought I could use the API to actually show a calendar and be able to make edits just like you can on google. It's looking like that isn't really possible.

Comment: i can assure you that it worked flawlessly on api V1 and obj-c gdata client, back in the "old" 2012 :)

Comment: anyway, i don't want any "widget calendar". I have my interface/ui on my app. Then, via HTTP POST, i'd like to send user and pwd of the user  of the app and insert the chosen event in his own calendar. Doesn't seem to difficult to me, even with OAUTH2 and API v3 :)  But i can't :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
On this page, when you click on the Create new Client Id, choose Web application and it shoudl give you the client secret key as well.

https://console.developers.google.com/project
Add a project etc.

Hope it helps